# Choosing between a good postdoc position and an assistant professorship

Tags: postdocs, career-path, research-assistantship

I have done a PhD (mathematics) at an average university and, while absolutely loving my line of research, these years were quite unsatisfactory, for diverse reasons. While working hard, I ended up having a quite low number of publications with respect to my peers in other groups or universities. Also, I grew quite tired of the city and its overall atmosphere.

Not finding better alternatives, I momentarily stayed as a postdoc and continued working on my field, finally starting to publish stuff (mostly with other groups) hoping to enhance my possibilities of eventually finding more appealing positions.

Eventually, it worked: I obtained a good postdoc offer. The position would be well-paid, in a reputable university full of great researchers, in a nice city and country full of perspectives and opportunities, and also extending to a sufficiently long period not to have to worry about searching another job soon; but clearly the issue would present itself sooner or later.

Meanwhile, my current institution has opened a number of assistant professorships, one of these in my field. These are not tenure-track positions but, by winning one of them, it is fairly likely that I would ultimately land on an actual tenure-track position: a thing that cannot be underestimated in such an overcrowded job market like academia is. Conversely, the salary is sensibly lower than the one comprised in the postdoc offer, and of course I would still find myself in the same environment (now with loads of teaching duties in the way too, to which I'm completely unprepared).

So, in the case I'll win the assistant professorship, I will find myself at a crossroads:
take it with all its disadvantages, or accept the postdoc challenge and see what I can do in a likely better environment?

Obviously only I am entitled to take the decision; nevertheless, I am hoping to find some advice from some more experienced people who may have found themselves in similar situations.

Thanks in advance and good holidays!

Comment: This is an opinion-based question. I think most answers will converge to taking the postdoc position but there are several factors that you alone are aware of; Family, What will boot your career, etc. One hint: you can always collaborate with other researchers even if they are not in the same university. (Actually, sometimes it works much better)

Comment: I was in a similar situation. It depends on the postdoc and the asst. prof job. The postdoc was literally my top choice, and I was interested in doing a postdoc. What was good about the prof job? Well, I would be a prof... I'm a postdoc currently.

Comment: Are you able to find out where people who took each path eventually went? If you can see a path to a place you want to go it may be easier to decide.

Comment: " it is fairly likely that I would ultimately land on an actual tenure-track position" -- this I assume is a guess.   Things could change.  We may have another pandemic for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a couple of things to think about:

1. How badly do you want any academic position?

Would you prefer getting any permanent academic position at all, no matter where, what teaching load, etc; over not getting an academic position and going for another career path (with a PhD in Mathematics, involuntary unemployment is not a likely prospect)? The answer will tell you whether playing it safe and/or settling for a less exciting position is something you should do or not.

2. Would the assistant professorship be something you do primarily in the hope that your university will show its gratitude and give a tenure-track position down the line?

It seems unwise to me to treat a temporary position as being on the "tenure-track-track". If your university had the will and the ability to make some kind of commitment, they would have gone for a tenure-track position straight-away. Counting on an unwritten reward down the line is how people get burned.

3. Would you like to ultimately end up at an institution that cares a lot about teaching?

Some places hire great researchers and hope that they can teach, other institutions really want to be sure that their tenure-track staff can teach well. If you aim for the latter, getting some teaching experience now is actually a great asset. If you aim for the former, continue concentrating on getting good papers out.

4. Carefully inspect the assistant professorship regarding its nature.

The usual advice that going for an assistant professorship over a postdoc is based on the assumption that the former is tenure-track. If it isn't, is it really "above" a postdoc in a meaningful way? Or is it just a fancy title for a teaching-heavy postdoc-style position?